# Construct class in a thread Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a class:

```
class Fee:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fie = foe()

    def foo(self):
        return bar
```

How can I create an instance of Fee but into a thread; run the constructor of Fee into a thread ?

Comment: While that's a straightforward thing to do, it also suggests you may be choosing a very strange design, or not quite understanding how classes work. Constructing a class instance isn't usually expected to have the kind of side effects that a thread's target callable should have.

Comment: You can execute a function in a new thread. The function can then create a new `Fee` object (which runs the concstructor).

Comment: I don't understand how your class is returning `bar` if it wasn't initialized with it...If `bar` is a global variable that seems like it could get out of hand fast

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a thread should be used solely to return a class, but if you'd like to *incorporate* a class into a thread you could try something like:

```
import threading

class Fee:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fie = 42

    def print_fie(self):
        print(self.fie)


def build_thread():
    new_fee_instance = Fee()
    new_fee_instance.print_fie()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=build_thread)
    my_thread.start()
    my_thread.join()
```

Result:

42

Process finished with exit code 0

I'm not sure if this is the cleanest way to build a class in a thread, but I think my logic with them is typically to have a thread attached to a function -> that function builds a class and uses it. I'm not sure what motivations you have to create a thread solely to return a class and not do any processing with it, but I imagine the overhead to creating a thread for such a purpose would negatively impact your program's speed because there is overhead to creating threads and that could be avoided.